# how to call non static webmethod form client static method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I' m trying to do something but I'm not sure if it is allowed in c# here is what I'm tring:

I have a Web Method which is not a static here it is:

```
   [WebMethod]
    public Byte[] recStuff(Byte[] recstuffile)
    {
        myfile = Unzip(muStuff);

        return null;
    }
```

and here is my client:

```
 public static  XmlDataService.StufServiceSoapClient lhaservice = null;
        public static void Autoupload()
        {
            string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(XMLStuffName);
            string text = fileContents;
            byte r2 = Zip(text);
            lhaservice.recStuff(r2);
        }
```

I am getting Error that:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

what can I do here?

Comment: What is `lhaservice`?

Comment: Check lhaservice != null. If not initialize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any case you have to instantiate `lhaservice` first before you use it in your (static) constructor:

```
lhaservice = new XmlDataService.StufServiceSoapClient();
```

...but unless you show all your relevant code we don't really know for sure what the problem could be in your code.

Note: **avoid static classes and operations** if they don't make any sense. Make them non-static and create an instance before using the `Autoupload` operation. Your code will become more flexible and testable. So you might want to rethink your code.

Answer (score 2):

It is very logical. lhaservice  = null. Initialize it.